# How can I make my script work with an array?

Tags: javascript

This Javascript controls a Monial Content box with forward and back buttons to move forwards or backwards but it only works for 2 DIVs, how can I make this script work with an array so I can add more elements?

e.g.

**Current Script Diagram**

[image]

**The Script Code**

```
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
   showQuote();
   $(".left").click(function(e) {
      $("#monial_btn_1").trigger("click"); 
   });
   $(".right").click(function(e) {
      $("#monial_btn_2").trigger("click");
   });


   $("#monial_btn_1").click(function(e) {
       $(".monial_content_1").fadeIn("fast");
       $(".monial_content_2").fadeOut("fast");
       var obj=$(this);
       obj.removeClass();
       obj.addClass("monial_btn_selected");

       obj=$("#monial_btn_2");
       obj.removeClass();
       obj.addClass("monial_btn");
   });

   $("#monial_btn_2").click(function(e) {
       $(".monial_content_1").fadeOut("fast");
       $(".monial_content_2").fadeIn("fast");
       var obj=$(this);
       obj.removeClass();
       obj.addClass("monial_btn_selected");

       obj=$("#monial_btn_1");
       obj.removeClass();
       obj.addClass("monial_btn");
   });
```

Comment: TIL what "monial" means :-)

Comment: @Pointy: What does TIL mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 10
for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
   $("#monial_btn_" + i).click(function(e) {
       $(".monial_content_" + i).fadeIn("fast");
       $(".monial_content_" + (i + 1)).fadeOut("fast");
       var obj=$(this);
       obj.removeClass();
       obj.addClass("monial_btn_selected");

       obj=$("#monial_btn_" + (i + 1));
       obj.removeClass();
       obj.addClass("monial_btn");
   });
}
```